# A new environment in the memoir class

Tags: environments, memoir

I write my thesis with the memoir class and want to include an Acknowledgment in the same style as the standard abstract from the memoir class. How can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a new environment `acknowledgments` that behaves like `abstract` but prints `Acknowledgments`:

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}
{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgments}\abstract}
{\endabstract}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newenvironment{acknowledgments}
{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgments}\abstract}
{\endabstract}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Some Text
\end{abstract}
\bigskip
\begin{acknowledgments}
Some Text
\end{acknowledgments}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to modify some file to have the new environment pop up in the LyX drop-down menu?

Comment: @Arrow I'm sorry I don't know LyX at all...